# Styling Pseudo Elements on hover

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a tag like ribbon created using the pseudo elements. 
Here's the code.

[**JSfiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9eLup6m3/)

```css
.skills-tag {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding:2.5px 10px;
  background:#e8e8e8;
  color:#6e6e6e !important;
  text-decoration:none;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:4px;
  border-top-left-radius:4px;
}
.skills-tag:after {
  margin-top: -2px;
  content:"";
  margin-left: 9px;
  position:absolute;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-color:transparent transparent transparent #e8e8e8;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:12px 0 12px 12px; 
}
.skills-tag:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="skills-tag">Tag 1</a>
<a href="#" class="skills-tag">Tag 2</a>
<a href="#" class="skills-tag">Tag 3</a>
```

When I hover on the element, I can change the background color as in the code, but How do I add an effect (border in this case ) when I hover on the native element?

Comment: you want a border around the arrow part of the element too?

Comment: @MicroR I'd prefer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just alter the color of left border of the `:after` pseudo-element as well:

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9eLup6m3/1/)**

```css
.skills-tag:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}

.skills-tag:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #ddd;
}
```

Note that in CSS selectors, pseudo-elements come at the end (after pseudo-classes).